# Selecting specific table from database VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
Public Sub UserList_SelectedIn(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "\users.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Chart1.Series.Add("Score") 'Adds the graph into the program
    Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Score], [Month] FROM * WHERE Table ='" & UserList.SelectedItem, myConnection)
    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader = cmdd.ExecuteReader
    While dr2.Read
        Chart1.Series("Score").Points.AddXY(dr2("Month").ToString, dr2("Score").ToString) 'Adds the month/score to the graph
    End While

End Sub
```

Trying to find a way to make the following line of code allow me to select data from a specific table that the user can choose from a listbox.

`Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Score] FROM * WHERE Table ='" & UserList.SelectedItem, myConnection)`

It gives the error when running: `Syntax error in FROM clause.`

I'm guessing it's because of the * after FROM.

Comment: You need to use the form `"SELECT [Score], [Month] FROM [" & UserList.SelectedItem.ToString & "]"`

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but I need 50+ rep to comment... but it should show you how to structure your query

`SELECT [column] FROM [table] WHERE [condition]`

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to add comment to say you need another " ' " at the end of the command, but also, I've never seen FROM * used in a command like that. Not saying it's wrong, I just have never seen it :). Anyways, this should help out with the issue, dont forget to bracket tables and fields if they contain wildcards or spaces in the names. Brackets can be used even if do not contain spaces or wildcards.

```
Public Sub UserList_SelectedIn(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserList.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
dataFile = "\users.accdb"
connString = provider & dataFile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
Chart1.Series.Add("Score") 'Adds the graph into the program

Dim Table_Str As String = "[" & UserList.SelectedItem & "]"

Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Score], [Month] FROM " & Table_Str, myConnection)

Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader = cmdd.ExecuteReader
While dr2.Read
    Chart1.Series("Score").Points.AddXY(dr2("Month").ToString, dr2("Score").ToString) 'Adds the month/score to the graph
End While

End Sub
```

You can also add in If statements or error checking before running the code to make sure a selection has been made from the user.

Hth
Chicken

Comment: Turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

Turning on Option Strict will force you to use .ToString .SelectedItem is an object and Option Strict requires an explicit conversion. Not too many extra keystrokes but it could save your runtime errors.

```
 Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Score], [Month] FROM [" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "]", myConnection)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Thanks, I always like an opportunity to plug Option Strict. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Laziness will do you no good. You should try to write all the table names after the FROM clause. Maybe that will solve it.